# Ознакомительное activity

Tags: java, android, xml, activity

Как реализовать это ознакомительное диалоговое окошко с показом возможностей приложения.

[image: как это реализовать]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создаете активность с контейнером ViewPager
2. Создаете столько фрагментов, сколько вам надо. В каждом фрагменте содержится разметка текущего ознакомительного слайда
3. Profit

Если надо сделать неподвижные кнопки внизу, то структура примерно такая будет

```
<linearlayout>
  viewPager
  <linearLayout>
    button
  </linearLayout>
</linearlayout>
```

Примеров по работе с viewPager и его адаптере великое множество в интернете. И, как сказал @pavlofff теперь можно запускать либо как новую активность, либо в диалоге просто возвращая это все в view виде.